# Draw a cured with style dashed in React Native

Tags: react-native, user-interface, react-native-svg

I'm trying draw a curved with style is dahsed like the picture below

[image]

I'm using component Line in react-native-svg but only get the result as shown below

[image]

How can draw curves? Many thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `react-native-svg`, you can define a `Path` component that represents your curve. For example:

```
const SvgComponent = (props) => (
  <Svg
    viewBox="0 0 429 135"
    fill="none"
    {...props}
  >
    <Path
      d="M9 7c157.135 213.709 340.14 89.046 412 0"
      stroke="#000"
      strokeWidth={20}
      strokeDasharray="12 6"
    />
  </Svg>
)
```

In this case, I created a curve using [Figma](https://www.figma.com/). Then, I exported the SVG and subsequently imported it into the [SVGR Playround](https://react-svgr.com/playground/?native=true) to turn it into the above code (although I made a small modification and changed the `width` and `height` into a `viewbox` prop).

You can see it in action at [this Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/gYRvRftAb)

Comment: Hi bro, tell me more how can i rotate it in the specified direction

Comment: Did you create a file in Figma (which I linked to) and experiment with it? You may also want to look at the [Path documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths)